# Fortran Function error about conflicting with a name in the encompassing scoping unit

Tags: fortran, fortran90

I'm new in Fortran. what's the problem with this simple code?

```
program combinatorial
    Implicit none
    integer :: m, n, Fact
    integer :: Com
    Write (*,*) 'inter 2 number for m and n'
    Read (*,*) m,n
    Com = Fact (m)/(Fact(n)*Fact(m-n))

    Contains
    integer Function Fact(t)
        Implicit none
        Integer, intent(IN) :: t
        integer :: i, Ans       
        Ans = 1
        Do i=1, t
            Ans=Ans * i
        End do
        Fact = Ans
    End Function Fact
End program combinatorial
```

The error that i encounter is :

```
combinatorial.f90(10): error #6626: The name of the internal procedure conflicts with a name in the encompassing scoping unit.   [FACT]
    integer Function Fact(t)
-------------------------^
compilation aborted for combinatorial.f90 (code 1)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Fact` is `contain`ed within the program the compiler will generate an interface to it automatically.  By also declaring an `integer` thing called `Fact` you're giving the compiler conflicting instructions and it don't like that.  Just drop `Fact` from the line

```
integer :: m, n, Fact
```

The `encompassing scoping unit` referred to by the compiler is the program which contains (or *encompasses*) the function.

And, as an aside, you don't need to use the variable `Ans` in your definition of the function.  You could simply write

```
integer Function Fact(t)
    Implicit none
    Integer, intent(IN) :: t
    integer :: i       
    Fact = 1
    Do i=1, t
        Fact = Fact * i
    End do
End Function Fact
```

Unless you use a `result` clause on the `function` statement the compiler will behave as if it creates a variable of the same name as the function for returning the function's result.